# Using WCF for dynamically generated IIS rewrite rules in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, url-rewriting

I've got a ASP.NET MVC 4 client for which I would like to load the IIS rewrite rules dynamically from a CMS. The set up is IIS7.5 with URL rewrite module 2 and .NET 4.5.

I've been reading the article, 'http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module' but I would like to implement this using WCF instead of SQL Server. Does anyone know how to implement this?

The idea is that I can then control all rewrite rules from a CMS system instead of having to modify the web.config manually.

Or is it possible to use a dynamic config source in the web.config which points to and reads from a WCF service?

Comment: IF your cms application runs on sql server you may be able to just modify the rewrite provider tables with the cms services and iis will feed off of them. Otherwise you may want to look into this http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Yeah that's one option but involves dropping a DLL into the GAC. I was hoping there was another way of doing this... Thank you for your response by the way.